# Почему код не может найти файл?

Tags: c++, файлы, winapi, visual-c++, файловая-система

GetLastError возвращает ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, хотя в папке есть файлы попадающие под маску. В чем проблема? Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LPWSTR fileName = L"*.exe";
LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW data32;
HANDLE fileHandle;

int main(){
    fileHandle = FindFirstFileW(fileName, data32);
    printf("%08x\n", GetLastError());
    if(fileHandle != 0){
        while(FindNextFileW(fileHandle, data32)){
            MessageBoxW(0, data32->cFileName, L"File Found!", 0);
        }
    }
    FindClose(fileHandle);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В какой папке?.

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\1\Debug\

Comment: А ищет в какой папке?

Comment: В этой же. Даже если в fileName прописать C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\1\Debug\*.exe - результата не будет.

Comment: Будет результат, обязательно будет. Только надо писать без ошибок. К примеру, не `Debug*.exe`, а `Debug\*.exe`. Да и вообще путь надо всегда указывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки у вас такие:

1) Используете указатель на структуру `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`, но ее не создаете. Поэтому в `FindFirstFileW` передается мусор.

2) Ищете `*.exe` там, где их нет. Программа запускается в каталоге проекта, а не в каталоге `Debug`. Понятно, что поиск исполняемых файлов ничего не вернет. Путь всегда надо задавать явно.

3) Ну и мелочевка вроде присваивания `LPWSTR fileName = L"*.exe";` (адрес константы неконстантному указателю).

Вот исправленный вариант (ищет `*.*` чтобы понятнее было):

```
int main() {
  LPCWSTR fileName = L"*.*";
  WIN32_FIND_DATAW data32;
  HANDLE fileHandle;

  fileHandle = FindFirstFileW(fileName, &data32);
  if(fileHandle != NULL) {
    while(FindNextFileW(fileHandle, &data32)){
      MessageBoxW(0, data32.cFileName, L"File Found!", 0);
    }
    FindClose(fileHandle);
  }
  else
    printf("%08x\n", GetLastError());

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не скажу, что **все** проблемы в этом, но...

Читаем в описании:

```
BOOL FindNextFileW(
  HANDLE             hFindFile,
  LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW lpFindFileData
);
```

> `lpFindFileData`
>   A pointer to the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure that receives information about the found file or subdirectory.

Как минимум - где ваша структура?

Подготовьте ее и передайте адрес:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
...
FindFirstFileW(fileName, &ffd);
```

Еще - если файл единственный, он будет найден `FindFirstFile` (и информация о нем не выведена), а `FindNextFile` находить будет уже нечего.

Еще - зачем вам в консольном приложении `MessageBox`?

Опять же - если это C++, то почему бы не воспользоваться [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem)?